# Align 4 labels horizontally with auto layout in swift

Tags: swift, autolayout, alignment, uilabel, uistoryboard

i want to align 4 labels horizontally.
This is what i do with constraints in my storyboard :
[image]

It's correct for iphone  5 :

[image]

It's not correct for others Iphone like Iphone 6 : 
[image]

How can i do ? I tried to embed my 4 labels in a view but it's not working too.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The last box doesn't have a width constraint, as the other 3 have. Just add it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Put in a "positioning" label in between labels 2 and 3. This label is just used to set the center point in auto layouts. Once you've centered this label, you can then set the other labels to be a fixed distance from this center layout.

The result will be the gutter to the left of the 1st label and to the right of the 4th label will expand/shrink based on the device size.

Be sure to put no content or styling on this positioning label, it won't be visible.